# Switch URL in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, url, google-chrome-extension

Preface: I'm a beginner to this stuff.

I'm trying to make an extension that replaces the current tab url with a predefined url. So far I have the following:

```
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
      chrome.tabs.update(tabs.id, {url: "https://www.wikipedia.org/"});
    });
```

The chrome app developer tool tells me that "tabs is not defined" but I have "tabs" in my manifest permissions. Manifest:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "declarativeContent",
    "https://www.wikipedia.org/"
],

"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
},

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon-19.png",
    "default_title": "Simple-Switch"
}
```

Comment: You are probably trying to run this from a context script. Correct?

Comment: I don't know if I'm trying to run it from a context script. I have a manifest file and a javascript file. The top one that I posted is the in the javascript and the lower one is in the manifest.

Comment: Please post your manifest then

Comment: I've updated the original post.

Comment: Okay, what do you want to trigger the change? When do you want it to activate?

Comment: I would like it to switch the url when the user clicks on the browser action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions don’t declare variables that you can use (as if there were a "`var tabs`"); they define what functions you are allowed to use (in this case, that you can call functions in `chrome.tabs`).

Your problem is that your callback takes an argument of `tab`, but you use the variable `tabs`.  Hence "tabs is not defined".  So the simplest fix would be `function(tabs)`.  But you should also use [`tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) instead of the deprecated [`tabs.getSelected`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected):

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: "https://www.wikipedia.org/"});
});
```

You can also change the `tabs` permission to `activeTab`.

Comment: D'oh! Good catch, @Teepeemm, because it's easy to confuse it with `chrome.tabs` not being available. Voted to close as typo.

Comment: @Xan I agree a typo was the root cause, but I’m not sure if it would be right to close this as such.  Part of the problem was that OP saw the appropriate error message, but interpreted it incorrectly (“I have ‘tabs’ in my manifest”).  Another way to look at it would be if someone thought `”permissions”: [“foo”]` implied the existence of `foo.id`.